# Does the STL include an iterator that works on arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stl, iterator

I want to use STL algorithms on pointers and statically allocated arrays, but they all want iterators. Is there any iterator that will take an array and a length and let me use that?

P.S. I'm aware of the `array` class in C++0x, but I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: Iterators were designed to work with container classes as well as arrays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointers *are* random-access iterators! You can simply pass a pointer to the start of the array, and a pointer to one past the end. Functions like these (included in C+11) may come handy:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T(&array)[N]) { return array; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T(&array)[N]) { return begin(array) + N; }
```

Comment: `struct overly_pedantic { void* operator&() const { return nullptr; } };` :)

Comment: @GManNickG Oh, that :( I always forget about operator&.

Comment: Yeah, sucks because I really like the way `&array[0]` reads in my head, but the Dumb Operator ruins that.

Comment: That's why we have `std::addressof`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array directly. For example,

```
int a[5] = .....;
std::for_each( a, ar + 5, someFunctor() );
```